# What is the technical term of these temporary data holders?

Tags: python, django

I've never read anything about created temporary data in your views that attach to models but I just played around with it and everything seems to work great. I was wondering if anyone knows the technical name for this so I can learn more about its flexibility.

In my django views I have

```
for todo in my todolist:
    todo.shorthand = todo.user + todo.name
    todo.active    = len(Posting.objects.filter(user=todo.user)
...
context = {'todolist':todolist}
```

Both shorthand and active are no model fields in the model but if I set these in my view I can call them in my template with something like this...

```
{% for todo in todolist|dictsortreversed:"active" %}
  <p> {{todo.shorthand}} {{todo.active}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Not only can I create the temporary data, but I can also use it with dictsort and other filters. If this is a new discovery, then awesome.

Comment: They're just normal attributes of python objects. There's nothing particularly special about the fact that they're not in your database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical term for this. You can create additional arbitrary attributes on your Python instances. Because these attributes are not defined on your model, all that happens is that Django won't persist them back to the database.

Django usually creates new instances for you when you query for objects from the database, but these objects *may* be cached across requests. When they do, then those attributes you created would still be there. Your code needs to take that possibility into account.

In this case, you assign new values to these attributes for your view, overriding any previous values you may have set before.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you *can't* create arbitrary attributes on instances whose classes define [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: @LukasGraf: since we are dealing with Django models here, that'd be a rare occurrence.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I learn how to cache across requests for these attributes?